# DuplicateKey exception

Tags: spring

I am running a spring web application with MySQL database. I get the following error.

```
ec 09, 2013 6:33:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [login] in context with path [/Loginwithmysql] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.getExceptionTranslator(JdbcAccessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:636)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:665)
```

Comment: I added the latest spring-tx jar as external jar in java build path. Still I get the following error:

HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DuplicateKeyException

Answer (score 0):

The class `DuplicateKeyException` is part of the `spring-tx` library. You will need to add it to your classpath. You can get it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx).