# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to use a createQuery to get data.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet spring-mvc threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.openSession(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: google  org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException

Answer (score 3):

Download `org.springframework.transaction.jar` andd add it to your classpath.

Comment: I had add spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar and org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar to my class path,but it still don't work.

Comment: Is your application running from IDE or on a application server?

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483939/duplicatekey-exception)

The class DuplicateKeyException is part of the spring-tx library. You will need to add it to your classpath. You can get it here.

Comment: I had add spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar and org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar to my class path,but it still don't work.

Answer (score -2):

DuplicateKeyException exception thrown when an attempt to insert or update data results in violation of an primary key or unique constraint. Note that this is not necessarily a purely relational concept; unique primary keys are required by most database types.

Comment: As you see, the class is not even found.

Comment: I try to request the default index.jsp page, the exception is still exist.

Comment: @XiaoRun Do you have spring-tx jar in your project? If yes. Please check it added to build path or not.